# Function signature, pass by value vs reference difference

Tags: c++, function, reference

I'm pretty confused with c++ since I was working with python all the time. So here is the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

    void print(const boost::system::error_code& e,
               boost::asio::steady_timer* t, int count) {
                if (count < 5) {
                    std::cout << count << std::endl;
                    ++(count);
                    t->expires_at(t->expiry() + 
                    boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
                    t->async_wait(boost::bind(print,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count));
                }
    }
    
    int main() {
        boost::asio::io_context io;
        int count = 0;
        boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
        t.async_wait(boost::bind(print,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, count));
        io.run();
          std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The following output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Final count is 0
```

Even if I change the signature to use int& count:

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& e,
           boost::asio::steady_timer* t, int& count)
```

The output is still the same.
What's the point of reference operator?

btw. I know I can do sth like int* count to have the final count 5, but that's not the point of my question.
btw2. Do you recommend any oreilly c++ books which are designated for people from other programming language?

Comment: `boost::bind` stores passed arguments by value, so you always oparates on copy data, and signature doesn't play role here. If you want to modify passed `count`, pass it by `boost::ref` (it keeps a pointer to `count` variable) with `int& count` in signature of handler.

Comment: @rafix07 Great it works. Thank You. But why doesn't c++ warn you when you pass reference to function which expects value and the other way?

Comment: @MatG what's your point? I understand the difference between pass by reference and value. I just couldn't get why passing reference wasn't modifying the object. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::bind` returns a function object. It stores a `count` as data member:

```
class Functor {
     int copyCount;
};
```

when calling `boost::bind` this `int` is copied. Functor provides function call operator which invokes bound `print` function:

```
class Functor {
     int copyCount;
public:
     void operator()() {
         print(...,copyCount);  // [1]
     }
};
```

in [1] `copyCount` is passed into `print` function. Because it is plain type, there is no matter it is passed by copy or by reference. If it would be complex data type, where a copy operation is heavy, `print(ComplexData&)` would be preferred, to avoid unnecessary copy.

By `boost::ref` you wrap `count` varaible into a pointer to int. So you operate on original object. And you can modify it.